Function composed with itself $q$ times returning $qx$
I am curious whether there exists a function $f:\Bbb R→\Bbb R$ such that $f^q (x)=qx$, where $f^n=f\circ f\circ f\circ f\ldots n$ and $q∈\Bbb N$.
The idea for this question came in when I was solving a problem in the Mathematical correspondence seminar. The task was to find all f(x) such that GCD(a,b) = GCD($f^b$(a), $f^a$(b)) for all a,b $∈\Bbb P$.
I wondered what would happen if the task was instead to find LCM(a,b) = LCM($f^b$(a), $f^a$(b)). And one of the options would clearly be if $f^a$(b)= $f^b$(a) = ab.
I didn't have much success finding the solution online. Even if there is a lecture discussing a similar function, they usually have the value of $q$ beforehand. The function I am trying to find, or disprove the existence of, has the property that when nested into itself $q$ times, will return the product of $x$ and $q$.
Any guidance will be appreciated. Thanks.

Function from what to what?   Is this meant to hold for all $q$ or just for one $q$?

Well, if it's true for all values, then it is true for $q=1$, so $f(x)=x$, which of course fails for all other $q$.

More generally, if $f^p(x)=px$ and $f^q(x)=qx$ for two distinct positive integers $p$ and $q$, then $f^{pq}(x)$ equals both $p^qx$ and $q^px$, and so $p^q=q^p$; the only nontrivial solution of this is ${p,q}={2,4}$.

Yes there is... kind of. If you only consider $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, then I think there is no such function (see below). However, if you allow $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, then the property can be achieved by simple addition: Choose $f$ s.t. $f(a,b) = a+b$ for all $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. Then fix lets say the second argument of the function as $x$, so in simple words $b = x$, and perform the composition in the first argument. Then you get e.g.
\begin{align}
f(0, x) =& x,
\\
[f(\cdot, x)](x) = x+x =& 2x,
\\
[f(\cdot, x) \circ f(\cdot, x) ](x) = 2x + x =& 3x,
\\
\vdots
\\
f^q(x) = \sum_{i = 1}^q x =& qx.
\end{align}
So if you are willing to allow such mappings you can achieve the desired property.
Now regarding the property for functions $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Assume you have a function $f$ such that $f(x) = x, (f \circ f)(x) = 2x, ..., f^{q}(x) = qx$. Notice that for $q=1$ the function is given explicitly as the identity. But $(Id \circ Id)(x) \neq 2x$. So there is a contradiction. You can construct such contradiction for general $q$.
Edit: As I have now seen, while I was writing this answer, the counterexamples were also given in the comments.
Edit II: The person asking the question specified that $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. So the first part of the answer is now obsolete. I will still let it as it is. Maybe someone will still find something useful in it.
